# Modify Drawable inside SpannableStringBuilder and DynamicLayout

Tags: android, android-drawable, spannablestring, imagespan

I'm trying to hide a smiley in a `SpannableStringBuilder` (which is used in a `DynamicLayout`).
At first I tried

```
ImageSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, length, ImageSpan.class);
spans[0].getDrawable().setAlpha(0);
```

It didn't work.
I also tried

```
ImageSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, length, ImageSpan.class);
spans[0].getDrawable().setVisible(false, true);
```

Didn't work either.

The next code did work, but it doesn't preserve the size of the drawable, so the text around the smiley starts to "jump", that is not correct.

```
ImageSpan[] spans = spannable.getSpans(0, length, ImageSpan.class);
spannable.removeSpan(spans[0]);
```

Potentially, I could redraw the drawable, but it's an expensive operation.  Why doesn't the drawable update? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in my base drawable class I implemented the `setAlpha` method in which I changed the paint object. After that I revalidated the view in which the drawable was. After that the `draw` method in my drawable class gets executed and the alpha value changes